# Is an infinitely recursive type useful?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Lately I've been experimenting with the general question, *what will GHC allow me to do?* I was surprised to find, that it considers the following program as valid

```
module BrokenRecursiveType where

data FooType = Foo FooType

main = print "it compiles!"
```

At first I thought, *how is this useful?* Then I remembered that Haskell is lazy, so I could, perhaps, define a function like the following to use it

```
allTheFoos = Foo allTheFoos
```

Then I thought, *so how is this useful?*

Are there any valuable use cases (thought up or actually experienced) for types of similar form to `FooType`?

Comment: A conjecture: every extant language either allows you to do something that isn't useful, or is so restrictive that it is useless as a whole.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### An evaluation counter

You could, hypothetically, use `FooType` to optionally abort a recursive function early: For example, take this code:

```
foo _ 0 = 1
foo (Foo x) n = n * foo x (n-1)
```

If you call `foo allTheFoos`, then you get the plain factorial function. But you can pass a different value of type `FooType`, e.g.

```
atMostFiveSteps = Foo (Foo (Foo (Foo (Foo (error "out of steps")))))
```

and then `foo atMostFiveSteps` will only work for values smaller than 6.

I’m neither saying that this is particularly useful nor that this is the best way to implement such a feature...

### A void type

BTW, there is a similar construction, namely

```
newtype FooType' = Foo' FooType'
```

which is useful: It is one way to define the void type that has no values besides ⊥. You can still define

```
allTheFoos' = Foo' allTheFoos'
```

as before, but because operationally, `Foo` does nothing, this is equivalent to `x = x` and hence also ⊥.

Answer (score 4):

Let's just slightly extend your data type - let's wrap the recursion into a type parameters:

```
data FooType f = Foo (f (FooType f))
```

(so your original data type would be `FooType Identity`).

Now we can modulate the recursive reference by any `f :: * -> *`. But this extended type is extremely useful! In fact, it can be used to express any recursive data type using a non-recursive one. One well kwnown package where it's defined is *recursion-schemes*, as [`Fix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:Fix):

```
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

For example, if we define

```
data List' a r = Cons' a r | Nil'
```

then `Fix (List' a)` is isomorphic to `[a]`:

```
nil :: Fix (List' a)
nil = Fix Nil'

cons :: a -> Fix (List' a) -> Fix (List' a)
cons x xs = Fix (Cons' x xs)
```

Moreover, `Fix` allows us to define many generic operations on recursive data types such as folding/unfolding ([catamorphisms/anamorphisms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6941904/1333025)).

Answer (score 1):

```
data FooType = Foo FooType

allTheFoos = Foo allTheFoos
```

I think there are two useful ways to look at this type.

First is the "moral" way—the common approach where we pretend that Haskell types don't have "bottom" (non-terminating) values.  From this perspective, `FooType` is a **unit type**—a type that has only one value, just like `()`.  This is because if you forbid bottoms, then the only value of type `Foo` is your `allTheFoos`.

From the "immoral" perspective (where bottoms are allowed), `FooType` is either an infinite tower of `Foo` constructors, or a finite tower of `Foo` constructors with a bottom at the bottom.  This is similar to the "moral" interpretation of this type:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

...but with bottom instead of zero, which means that you can't write functions like this one:

```
plus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
plus Zero y = y
plus (Succ x) y = Succ (x `plus` y)
```

Where does that leave us?  I think the conclusion is that `FooType` isn't really an useful type, because:

1. If you look at it "morally" it's equivalent to `()`.
2. If you look at it "immorally" it's similar to `Nat` but any functions that tries to match a "zero" is non-terminating.

Comment: `allTheFoos` _is_ the bottom, isn't it?

Comment: @ErikAllik: No, because pattern matching on it will always succeed.

Comment: oh right: just an infinite stream of a useless value.

Answer (score 1):

An extension of your FooType could be an abstract syntax tree. Taking a simple example language only having integers, sums and inverses, the type definition would be

```
data Exp = AnInt Integer
         | AnInverse Exp
         | ASum Exp Exp
```

All the following would be Exp instances:

```
AnInt 2  -- 2
AnInverse ( AnInt 2 )  -- 1 / 2
AnInverse ( ASum ( AnInt 2 ) ( AnInt 3 ) )  -- 1 / ( 2 + 3 )
AnInverse ( ASum 1 ( AnInverse 2 ) )  -- 1 / ( 1 + 1 / 2 )
```

If we removed AnInt and ASum from the Exp definition, the type would be isomorphic to your FooType (with AnInverse replacing Foo).

Answer (score 0):

The following type:

```
newtype H a b = Fn {invoke :: H b a -> b}
```

while not exactly the same as yours but is in a similar spirit, have been shown by Launchbury, Krstic, and Sauerwein to have interesting uses regarding corouitining: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5135.pdf